# Can't open a port on Cent OS 7

Tags: ssh, firewall, iptables, port, nmap

I'm getting this error in my app:

```
Call From master/192.168.X.X to localhost:11111 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

And indeed ssh fails:

```
[user@master API_test]$ ssh localhost -p 11111
ssh: connect to host localhost port 11111: Connection refused
```

Then I've opened it in firewall:

```
[user@master test]$ sudo iptables -L
.......
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:11111 ctstate NEW
```

But still nmap doesn't show that port as open:

```
[user@master API_test]$ nmap master

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-01-19 06:00 PST
Nmap scan report for master (192.168.X.X)
Host is up (0.00049s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
111/tcp open  rpcbind

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The simplest explanation for "connection refused" is that nothing is listening for connections on the port you're trying to connect to. Could you run something like `netstat -na | grep 11111` and [edit] your question to include the netstat output?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to connect to port `11111`, but you have opened `111111` in iptables.

`11111 != 111111`

Fix iptables to open the correct port.

Comment: Good catch, but I've just edited the outputs, I'm using correct port numbers. Corrected the port.

Comment: This just demonstrates that it makes debugging your problem more difficult, without any good reason.

Comment: Come on, I can use whatever port I use, and it doesn't make any difference, and doesn't change anything about the question. If you don't have the answer, just skip the question. It's not required to write something, especially if it doesn't help at all.